# Angular 4 - validator depending on list of valid values stored in a service

Tags: angular

I have a directive to validate that an input value is included in a list of values. This list of values is dynamic, so it is a parameter of the directive :

```
@Directive({
selector: '[lookup]',
providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: LookupDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class LookupDirective implements Validator {

    @Input() lookupCollection: Array<any>;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        return lookupValidator(this.lookupCollection)(control);
    }
}
```

In the html, the directive is used like this :

```
lookup [lookupCollection]="myService.valuesAsObservable | async"
```

Problem is, the validator is only called when the input changed, not when the observable submit a new value.

Also, I am not injecting the service in the directive because depending on the component, the service used is not the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an acync validator that uses an arbitrary param rather than AbstractControl. This will allow you to be in full control when to call it. Take a look at this sample app:
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/Angular4/form-samples/src/app/async-validator

In particular, see how I use the method checkWorkAuthorizationV2() in the service. In that example, I subscribe to valueChanges, but I could have called this method any time I wanted. After the method is returns, I use the method setErrors() on the form to show errors if any.

Comment: Problem is, we are currently using template-driven forms, not reactive. I know it is not the best way, but I don't want, if possible, to refactor the whole thing because of this.

Comment: No need to refactor. Just invoke the validation method from the ngSubmit() handler function.